# Create frequency tables for multiple factor columns in R

Tags: r, r-factor, sapply

I am a novice in R. I am compiling a separate manual on the syntax for the common functions/features for my work. My sample dataframe as follows:

```
x.sample <-
structure(list(Q9_A = structure(c(5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Impt", "Neutral", "Not Impt at all", 
"Somewhat Impt", "Very Impt"), class = "factor"), Q9_B = structure(c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Impt", "Neutral", 
"Not Impt at all", "Somewhat Impt", "Very Impt"), class = "factor"), 
Q9_C = structure(c(3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L
), .Label = c("Impt", "Neutral", "Not Impt at all", "Somewhat Impt", 
"Very Impt"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Q9_A", "Q9_B", 
"Q9_C"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

> x.sample
          Q9_A            Q9_B            Q9_C
1        Very Impt       Very Impt Not Impt at all
2  Not Impt at all       Very Impt       Very Impt
3        Very Impt       Very Impt       Very Impt
4  Not Impt at all Not Impt at all Not Impt at all
5        Very Impt       Very Impt       Very Impt
6  Not Impt at all       Very Impt       Very Impt
7             Impt Not Impt at all Not Impt at all
8        Very Impt       Very Impt       Very Impt
9        Very Impt Not Impt at all       Very Impt
10       Very Impt Not Impt at all Not Impt at all
```

My original dataframe has 21 columns.

If I want to find the mean (treating this as an ordinal variable):

```
> sapply(x.sample,function(x) mean(as.numeric(x), na.rm=TRUE))
Q9_A Q9_B Q9_C 
 4.0  4.2  4.2
```

I would like to tabulate a frequency table for ALL the variables in my dataframe. I searched the internet and many forums and saw that the nearest command to do this is using sapply. But when I did it, it gave all 0s.

```
> sapply(x.sample,function(x) table(factor(x.sample, levels=c("Not Impt at all", "Somewhat Impt",            "Neutral", "Impt", "Very Impt"), ordered=TRUE)))
                Q9_A Q9_B Q9_C
Not Impt at all    0    0    0
Somewhat Impt      0    0    0
Neutral            0    0    0
Impt               0    0    0
Very Impt          0    0    0
```

QUESTION
How can I make use of sapply to tabulate a frequency chart as per the above table for all the columns (that are factors) in a dataframe?

PS So sorry if this seems trivia but I have searched for 2 days without an answer and trying all possible combinations. Maybe I didn't search hard enough =(

Thanks very much.

Comment: Wouldn't `sapply(x.sample, table)` do it?

Comment: @RichardScriven - pretty much. That does everything but rearrange the output in line with the `factor` ordering.

Comment: @Richard Scriven: I tried your approach but it returned an error. "Invalid size arguement".

Comment: @RaphaelLee - it definitely works. Try your own `x.sample` from your question with the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were nearly there. Just one small change in your function would have got you there. The `x` in `function(x) ...` needs to be passed through to the `table()` call:

```
levs <- c("Not Impt at all", "Somewhat Impt", "Neutral", "Impt", "Very Impt")
sapply(x.sample, function(x) table(factor(x, levels=levs, ordered=TRUE)))
```

A little re-jig of the code might make it a bit easier to read too:

```
sapply(lapply(x.sample,factor,levels=levs,ordered=TRUE), table)

#                Q9_A Q9_B Q9_C
#Not Impt at all    3    4    4
#Somewhat Impt      0    0    0
#Neutral            0    0    0
#Impt               1    0    0
#Very Impt          6    6    6
```

Comment: I know I am not allowed to say "thanks" but you saved me a tremendous amount of effort searching endlessly on the internet. Anyway, a lazy way to do replace typing in all the levels would be to use: levs <- levels(x.sample$Q9_A).

Comment: @RaphaelLee - you definitely *are* allowed to say "thanks". Up-voting good answers and accepting the answer that works for you is also good etiquette.  Plus you also gain reputation when you accept an answer.

Answer (score 9):

Coming a bit late, but here's a `reshape2` possible solution. It could have been very straightforward with `recast` but we need to handle empty factor levels here so we need to specify both `factorsAsStrings = FALSE` within `melt` and `drop = FALSE` within `dcast`, while `recast` can't pass arguments to `melt` (only to `dcast`), so here goes

```
library(reshape2)
x.sample$indx <- 1 
dcast(melt(x.sample, "indx", factorsAsStrings = FALSE), value ~ variable, drop = FALSE)
#             value Q9_A Q9_B Q9_C
# 1            Impt    1    0    0
# 2         Neutral    0    0    0
# 3 Not Impt at all    3    4    4
# 4   Somewhat Impt    0    0    0
# 5       Very Impt    6    6    6
```

If we wouldn't care about empty levels a quick solution would be just

```
recast(x.sample, value ~ variable, id.var = "indx")
#             value Q9_A Q9_B Q9_C
# 1            Impt    1    0    0
# 2 Not Impt at all    3    4    4
# 3       Very Impt    6    6    6
```

---

Alternatively, if speed is a concern, we can do the same using `data.atble`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(x.sample), measure.vars = names(x.sample), value.factor = TRUE), 
           value ~ variable, drop = FALSE)
#              value Q9_A Q9_B Q9_C
# 1:            Impt    1    0    0
# 2:         Neutral    0    0    0
# 3: Not Impt at all    3    4    4
# 4:   Somewhat Impt    0    0    0
# 5:       Very Impt    6    6    6
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not just:

```
> sapply(x.sample, table)
                Q9_A Q9_B Q9_C
Impt               1    0    0
Neutral            0    0    0
Not Impt at all    3    4    4
Somewhat Impt      0    0    0
Very Impt          6    6    6
```

Let's call it 'tbl';

```
tbl[ order(match(rownames(tbl), c("Not Impt at all", "Somewhat Impt", 
                                  "Neutral", "Impt", "Very Impt")) )   , ]
                Q9_A Q9_B Q9_C
Not Impt at all    3    4    4
Somewhat Impt      0    0    0
Neutral            0    0    0
Impt               1    0    0
Very Impt          6    6    6
```

Comment: This would always return a matrix. Only if the number and names of levels is the same in every column would this work.

Comment: It does. It was my syntax error. Thank you so much!

Comment: I meant to write it _wouldn't_ always return a matrix.

Comment: Of course this works, but I thought OP was specifically looking to reorder the results as well. Whether that should be done by altering the data.frame itself first is up for debate I suppose.

Comment: I see what you mean. Perhaps by matching rownames to `c("Not Impt at all", "Somewhat Impt", "Neutral", "Impt", "Very Impt")`? I don't think the "ordered" attribute is needed as lon as levels are supplied.