# One hot coding a data-frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, package, data-cleaning

Consider a data-frame `df1` similar to the one shown

```
ID EDUCATION   OCCUPATION      BINARY_VAR
1  Undergrad   Student              1
2  Grad        Business Owner       1
3  Undergrad   Unemployed           0
4  PhD         Other                1
```

You may create your own random `df1` using R-code below

```
ID <- c(1:4)
EDUCATION <- sample (c('Undergrad', 'Grad', 'PhD'), 4, rep = TRUE)
OCCUPATION <- sample (c('Student', 'Business Owner', 'Unemployed', 'Other'), 4, rep = FALSE)
BINARY_VAR <- sample(c(0, 1), 4, rep = TRUE)
df1 <- data.frame(ID, EDUCATION, OCCUPATION, BINARY_VAR)

# Convert to factor
df1[, names(df1)] <- lapply(df1[, names(df1)] , factor)
```

From this, I need to derive another data-frame `df2` that would look like this

```
ID Undergrad Grad PhD Student Business Owner Unemployed Other BINARY_VAR
1      1      0    0     1           0           0        0       1
2      1      1    0     0           1           0        0       1
3      1      0    0     0           0           1        0       0
4      1      1    1     0           0           0        1       1
```

You must have noticed how for level `PhD`, the other factor levels under `EDUCATION` also hold true since `EDUCATION` is the highest education level for that `ID`. That, however, is the secondary objective.

I can't seem to figure out a way **to obtain a data-frame with each column giving the truth value corresponding to individual factor levels in its parent data-frame**. Is there a package **in R** that could help? Or maybe a way to code this?

Can I do this using `melt`?

I read through [previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291674/create-frequency-tables-for-multiple-factor-columns-in-r)(s) that *looked* similar, but they deal with frequencies of occurrence.

---

Edit:

As recommended by [Sumedh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5338586/sumedh), one way to do this is using `dummyVars` from `caret`.

```
dummies <- dummyVars(ID ~ ., data = df1)
df2 <- data.frame(predict(dummies, newdata = df1))
df2 <- df2 [1:7]
```

Comment: For your primary objective, you could use `dummyVars` from `caret` http://topepo.github.io/caret/preprocess.html

Comment: For PhD, you could use `df$Grad[df$PhD == 1]  <- 1` and `df$Undergrad[df$PhD == 1]  <- 1`. Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Worked! Any idea on how to obtain the actual goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tidyr` and `dplyr` combined with that `base table()` function should work:

```
ID <- c(1:4)
EDUCATION <- c('Undergrad', 'Grad', 'PhD', 'Undergrad')
OCCUPATION <- c('Student', 'Business Owner', 'Unemployed', 'Other')
BINARY_VAR <- sample(c(0, 1), 4, rep = TRUE)
df1 <- data.frame(ID, EDUCATION, OCCUPATION, BINARY_VAR)

# Convert to factor
df1[, names(df1)] <- lapply(df1[, names(df1)] , factor)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

edu<-as.data.frame(table(df1[,1:2])) %>% spread(EDUCATION, Freq)

for(i in 1:nrow(edu))
  if(edu[i,]$PhD == 1) 
    edu[i,]$Undergrad <-edu[i,]$Grad <-1

truth_table<-merge(edu,
      as.data.frame(table(df1[,c(1,3)])) %>% spread(OCCUPATION, Freq),
      by = "ID")

truth_table$BINARY_VAR<-df1$BINARY_VAR
truth_table

ID Grad PhD Undergrad Business Owner Other Student Unemployed BINARY_VAR
1    0   0         1              0     0       1          0          1
2    1   0         0              1     0       0          0          1
3    1   1         1              0     0       0          1          0
4    0   0         1              0     1       0          0          1
```

Edit: added a `for` loop to update the education levels beneath `PhD` inspired by @ Sumedh's earlier suggestion.

Comment: @Sumedh's solution works, except - the original data has 12 factor levels, so maybe I'd have to create a function do it in (somewhat) an iterative fashion over the levels. Also, there are some 160,000 rows ...