# Counting values within each column in R

Tags: r, count, apply

I'm trying to write a script  to count the values in the following dataframe called `results`.

```
Var1 | Var2|Var3 |Var4
----------------------
y    |n    |n    |n
n    |n    |n    |n
n    |y    |n    |n
n    |n    |n    |NA
NA   |n    |n    |n
```

I'm hoping to create another dataframe that looks something like this:

```
     |Var1 |Var2 |Var3 |Var4
----------------------------
n    |3    |4    |5    |4
y    |1    |1    |0    |0
NA   |1    |0    |0    |1
```

The closest I have come so far is by using the apply() function.

`newresults <- apply(results,2,table)`

but it's yielding something like this:

```
Var1.Var|Var1|Var2.Var|Var2|Var3.Var|Var3|Var4.Var|Var4 
---------------------------------------------------------------
n       |3   |n       |4   |n       |5   |n       |4    
y       |1   |y       |1   |n       |5   |n       |4
```

Is there a way to include all the variables, and count the variables within each column?

Comment: `sapply(results, function(x) table(factor(x,levels=c("n","y")), useNA="always") )` you need to make sure all of your table calls have the same values, which you can do via a factor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291674/create-frequency-tables-for-multiple-factor-columns-in-r